# Are Numbers As Validated Password Reset Is It Safe?

Tags: php, database, passwords

I have a table like the following:

```
|-------|-----------|-------------------|---------------|-----------|
|   id  |   name    |       email       |   password    |   code    |
|_______|___________|___________________|_______________|___________|
|       |           |                   |               |           |
|   1   |   user1   |   user1@gmail.com |   PASSWORD    |   8989    |
|_______|___________|___________________|_______________|___________|
|       |           |                   |               |           |
|   2   |   user2   |   user2@gmail.com |   PASSWORD    |   7676    |
|_______|___________|___________________|_______________|___________|
```

As you can see, there is a column of `code` that I fill with random. Why the column exists, and what is the purpose?
Initially, I had trouble creating a password reset page, then I created a unique `code` as the validation of each user.

**REGISTER**

```
<?php
include_once 'MySQLiConnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {

    $username = $Connection->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = $Connection->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $Connection->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $code = (rand(1111,9999));
    $hashed_pwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,code) VALUES('$username','$email','$hashed_pwd','$code')";

        if ($Connection->query($query)) {
            echo "Success";
            }
}
$Connection->close();
?>

<html>
<body>

<form method="post">
    <input type='text' name='username'/>
    <input type='email' name='email'/>
    <input type='password' name='password'/>
    <button type='submit' name='signup'>Register</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

After entering the data, and registering, the user has randomly generated `code`. Let's just say the `code` is 8989. Users will not know the `code`, and only know after requesting a password reset.

If the user forgets the password, then the user can reset it by entering the `code` into the field field that was previously received by email message.

**RESET PASSWORD**

```
<?php
include_once 'MySQLiConnect.php';
    $inputmail = $Connection->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $inputcode = $Connection->real_escape_string($_POST['code']);
    $newcode = (rand(1111,9999));
    $newpass = $Connection->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $hashed_pwd = password_hash($newpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if(isset($_POST['savepass'])) {

    $check_email = $Connection->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$inputmail."'");
    $user_check = $check_email->fetch_array();

if ($inputcode == $user_check['code']) {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET password='".$hashed_pwd."', code='".$newcode."' WHERE email='".$inputmail."'";

        if ($Connection->query($query)) {
            echo "Password updated";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Code wrong!";
    }
}
$Connection->close();
?>

<html>
<body>

<form method="post">
    <input type='email' name='email'/>
    <input type='text' name='code'/>
    <input type='password' name='password'/>
    <button type='submit' name='savepass'> Update </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The codes above I cut a lot and I took the important part only. Sorry if there might be something wrong. But for the original, work with no problems.

But why do I make this question?
I need your opinion on this trick, because I am not so sure whether the `code` is safe or potentially broken into by hackers. Because the `code` is written with plain text without encrypt.

Awaiting your suggestion. thanks.

Comment: A four-digit code is way to short. Use a proper __hash__, generated from some properties of the user object plus a random value - sha1 at least. Plus, you should implement a mechanism to make codes expire after a reasonable amount of time ("industry standard" would probably be 24 hours.) Create a new hash every time a user _requests_ a password reset; not before. Add a counter of attempts to request _new_ codes; and block the user account from doing so for an extended period of time, if that happens to often.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not.

If someone (somehow) gets a database dump from your site, they can login with each account using the in plain text stored code. Furthermore you are highly vulnerable to anyone attacking you using this angle: They only need to test the numbers 1000-9999 with each email combination. There is also no code in place to protect yourself against such mass login attempts.

Jeff Atwood recently blogged about [hash security](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hacker-hack-thyself/). If you are concerned about your user password protection, read it :)

If this is a publicly facing website, I would suggest allowing your users to login with their Facebook, Github, Google, ... accounts - whichever are appropriate for your target audience. This way you do not have to implement password reset at all. Let those companies worry how to do this securely for you...